# Mechanize and twitter

Tags: ruby, mechanize

How can I use mechanize and twitter? I used to send a twitter from su.pr but I would like to use mechanize to send it automatically for me! I know how to login but when I try to submit a post nothing happens I got this object:

http://pastie.org/2576760

do you know if it is because the javascript or am I missing something??

please help me!

Comment: You should use the Twitter API.

Answer (score 1):

See [the twitter gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter) - the readme page contains everything you need, look for "Update your status". :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an example oauth/twitter script in ruby some time ago, perhaps it could help you:

http://bitlong.org/articles/ruby_twitter